# Access an element of a vector given the vector's pointer

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector, stl

I am trying to create a sorting function with the parameters being a pointer of a list and I am trying to access an element of the given list. Hopefully this code speaks for the problem better than I can:

```cpp
void bubbleSort(std::vector<int> *L) {
    unsigned int i = 0; int temp;
    while(isSorted(*L)) {
        if(i==L->size()-1) {
            i = 0;
        }
        if(i<L[i]/*<-ERROR here.*/) {
            temp = L[i+1]; // ERROR HERE
            L[i+1] = L[i]; // ERROR HERE
            L[i] = temp; // ERROR HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to guess or think too much. Just apply rules that you know about. If you want to force a certain order of evaluation and you're not sure, add parentheses. Oh, and don't use pointers to begin with, that function is not usable with a null pointer anyway.

Comment: What other methods does a `vector` have?

Comment: The problem here is called "pointless use of pointers". This is where pointers are used without any valid reason to do so, such as here. Nothing gets accomplished by doing that except it adds an extra layer of confusion. Since `L` is a ***pointer to a vector*** `L[i]` is `i`th vector it's pointing to, instead of the `i`th value in the first vector the pointer is pointing to, as is your clear intention here.

Comment: As `L` is a pointer to a vector you need `(*L)[i]`  everywhere you try to index `L`.  You should probable pass `L` as a reference `void bubbleSort(std::vector<int> &L)` to avoid this.

Comment: Why not just pass the vector by reference rather than pointer? What's the point of using a pointer here?

Comment: Take a look at `std::swap()`.

Comment: `while (isSorted(*L))`...surely you meant `while (!isSorted(*L))`. I hope your `isSorted` method accepts the vector by reference, not by value

Comment: There are some style guides that use a pointer instead of a reference to make it clear reading the calling code (which has a & for affected parameters) that it's an out or in/out parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to painfully dereference every individual use of `L` (and indeed doing so is error-prone, as you've demonstrated by missing one in your answer).

Instead, just write:

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<int> *Lptr) {
  auto &L = *Lptr;
```

and keep the rest of the code the same.

---

NB. It would be even *better* to change the function itself, to

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<int> &L) {
```

as it should have been written in the first place, but I'm assuming there's some artificial reason you can't do that.

Comment: It would be even better yet to change it to `void bubbleSort(std::span<int> L) {`.

Comment: And just to top that: `template <typename T> void bubbleSort(std::span<T> L)`. Potentially `const T`.

Answer (score 0):

The function accepts a pointer to an object of type `std::vector<int>`.

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<int> *L) {
```

To access the original vector using the pointer, you can write either `*L` or `L[0]`. That is, both expressions yield an lvalue reference of type `std::vector<int> &` to the vector.

To get the `i-th` element of the vector using the subscript operator through the pointer, you can write either `(*L)[i]` or `L[0][i]`,

However, in this `if` statement:

```
if(i<L[i]/*<-ERROR here.*/) {
```

You are trying to compare the variable `i` of type `unsigned int` to the object `L[i]` of type `std::vector<int>`. When `i` is not equal to `0`, this yields a non-existent object of the vector type.

It seems you mean something like the following instead:

```
if ( (*L)[i] < (*L)[i+1] ) {
```

or:

```
if ( L[0][i] < L[0][i+1] ) {
```

or, vice versa:

```
if ( L[0][i+1] < L[0][i] ) {
```

Depending on whether the vector is sorted in ascending or descending order.

Pay attention to the fact that there is no sense in declaring the parameter as a pointer to a `std::vector<int>`. The function would be much clearer and readable if it accepted the vector by reference instead:

```
void bubbleSort(std::vector<int> &L) {
```

In this case, the `if` statement would look like this:

```
if ( L[i] < L[i+1] ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer to change the source code as other answer. But, for this question, you can use `->at()` function to access the element in a vector pointer.

```cpp
if(i<L->at(i)) {
   temp = L->at(i+1);
   L->at(i+1) = L->at(i);
   L->at(i) = temp;
}
```